# make App lose focus when NSWindow order out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

```
NSApplication *thisApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
[thisApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[self.window orderFrontRegardless];
```

I use the code above to make my App get focus when need to show the window, and I want to make the app lose focus when hide the window.

```
[self.window orderOut:self];
[self.window resignMainWindow];
[self.window resignKeyWindow];
```

the code above can't solve the problem. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to hide all the windows of your application you can just use `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:nil]`. This will automatically activate the next application in line. If you want to activate another application but still keep your application on screen, this is a bit harder. For Mac OS X 10.6+ you can use the [NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSRunningApplication) class to find the current application before you become active and then reactivate it after you are done.

Comment: Thanks, but you forget the param of hide, it should like this [[NSApplication sharedApplication] hide:nil]